# Removing delimiter from a Unix text file

Tags: unix, sed, character, text-processing

I have a question about removing delimiter character from a text file

Let's say I have this text inside the text file

> Hello-World

I wanna remove the (-) delimiter and keep the text

> HelloWorld

I already tried the following commande which removed all the text after delimiter

```
sed -e 's/-.*//'
```

Thank's in advance

Comment: `.*` matches any 0 or more chars, it will match all the rest of the `-`. Remove it. `sed 's/-//g' file > newfile`

Comment: It's just a typo while wrting the example, I just edited that thank you!

Comment: See https://ideone.com/D5CyeK

Answer (score 1):

Well, the `.` stands for any character, the `*` for zero or more occurences.

Try it like this

```
sed 's/-//'
```

to just remove the `-`. If you want to do this more than once, add the global tag.

```
sed 's/-//g'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the dots with

```
tr -d "." < textfile
```